# Using SELECT2 4.0.0 with infinite Data and filter

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select2 now since 2 years and I really enjoy all dev made. however, version 3.5.x has his limit, so I'm moving to version 4.0, which give me headaches!

For your record, I'm using Select2 with large table (> 10.000 entries), so AJAX & infinite data (page set to 50 items).

1. With version 3.5.2, I can reproduce the underline match when searching for data (using `formatSelection` and `query.term`). Any idea how to make it with version 4.0.0 (function `templateResult` only passes `result` and not `query` anymore?
2. With version 3.x, you can add free entries using search value was not in the list (using `createSearchChoice`). Version 4.0 does not have this option, any idea how to make it again?
3. I try to replace the Select bar with an input bar (still using the select dropdown). It seems possible to force the adapter but I was unable to find how.
4. I need to add either a line (at row 1) or a button (floating to the right) to add new item (similar to `createTag`, but for an item). has someone made it already?

Answer (score 21):

I'd highly recommend reading [the release notes](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases) and the [4.0 release announcement](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) when migrating from Select2 3.5.2 to Select2 4.0.0.

> With version 3.5.2, I can reproduce the underline match when searching for data (using formatSelection and query.term).. any idea how to make it with v4.0.0 (function templateResult only pass 'result' and not 'query' anymore ?

This was removed in 4.0 because the results have been separated from the queries, so it didn't make sense to keep passing along the information. Of course, *this doesn't mean you can't* get the query and store it. All you would need to do is store the query, something like the following might work

```
var query = {};
var $element = $('#my-happy-select');

function markMatch (text, term) {
  // Find where the match is
  var match = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase());

  var $result = $('<span></span>');

  // If there is no match, move on
  if (match < 0) {
    return $result.text(text);
  }

  // Put in whatever text is before the match
  $result.text(text.substring(0, match));

  // Mark the match
  var $match = $('<span class="select2-rendered__match"></span>');
  $match.text(text.substring(match, match + term.length));

  // Append the matching text
  $result.append($match);

  // Put in whatever is after the match
  $result.append(text.substring(match + term.length));

  return $result;
}

$element.select2({
  templateResult: function (item) {
    // No need to template the searching text
    if (item.loading) {
      return item.text;
    }

    var term = query.term || '';
    var $result = markMatch(item.text, term);

    return $result;
  },
  language: {
    searching: function (params) {
      // Intercept the query as it is happening
      query = params;

      // Change this to be appropriate for your application
      return 'Searching…';
    }
  }
});
```

> With version 3.x, you can add free entries using search value was not in the list (using createSearchChoice). V4.0 has not this option, any idea how to make it again ?

This can still be done in 4.0 using the `tags` option (set it to `true`). If you want to customize the tag, you can use `createTag` (similar to `createSearchChoice`).

```
var $element = $('#my-happy-select');

$element.select2({
  createTag: function (query) {
    return {
      id: query.term,
      text: query.term,
      tag: true
    }
  },
  tags: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Appreciate your effort (and time) to take to reply to questions and coding at the same time. However, for question #2, I do not want to add a free 'tag', but a free entry as a dropdownlist. any help ? Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between a free tag and a free entry? `createTag` is the same as the old `createSearchChoice`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The underline solution is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Oh my God. It's incredible the hard that was for me to find this. And understand the separation but it should be mandatory to have this out of the box :|

Answer (score 5):

Simple way to underline matched results with select2 4.x

```
$element.select2({

    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }
    ,
     templateResult: function (result) {
        return result.htmlmatch ? result.htmlmatch : result.text;
     }
    ,
    matcher:function(params, data) {
        if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
          return data;
        }
        if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
          return null;
        }

        var idx = data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(params.term.toLowerCase());
        if (idx > -1) {
          var modifiedData = $.extend({
              'htmlmatch': data.text.replace(new RegExp( "(" + params.term + ")","gi") ,"<u>$1</u>")
          }, data, true);

          return modifiedData;
        }

        return null;
    }
})
```