# how to make select2 search start alphabetical?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for tag searching in my article tracking app, and I noticed that when you start typing, say "m", "mi", you would think 'migrations' would highlight first, but instead it starts with anything that has 'm', like forms. As the pic shows, 'forms' comes up first, which becomes very annoying the more you search.

If you type 'mi', I expect anything starting with 'mi' to come up first, instead it will include things like 'forms-middle' that have m and i. How do you make select2 lookup tags correctly based on spelling? Thank you

The answer as is isn't working for some reason, neither is the default one provided in the doc:

```
<select  style="width:90%;" multiple="multiple" id="selected_tags" name="selected_tags">
      {% for tag in tags %}        
          <option value="{{tag.slug}}">{{tag.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>  

....


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selected_tags").select2({
        sortResults: function(results, container, query) {
            if (query.term) {
                // use the built in javascript sort function
                return results.sort(function(a, b) {
                    if (a.text.length > b.text.length) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (a.text.length < b.text.length) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
            }
            return results;
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html that was what I saw

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 - Sorting results by query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31991217/359284#32106792)

Comment: The answer there will work for Select2 4.0.0, while the code you are using is for Select2 3.5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the result please check the **[documentation here](http://select2.github.io/select2/#sort_results)**. Sort based on the queried string index. You can use javascript build in **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method to sort result array.

```js
$("#e1").select2({
  sortResults: function(results, container, query) {
    console.log(query);
    if (query.term) {
      // use the built in javascript sort function
      return results.sort(function(a, b) {
        console.log(a.text.indexOf(query),b.text.indexOf(query));
        if (a.text.indexOf(query.term) > b.text.indexOf(query.term)) {
          return 1;
        } else if (a.text.indexOf(query.term) < b.text.indexOf(query.term)) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
    }
    return results;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
<select id="e1">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  <option value="WY">sdsd</option>
  <option value="WY">aasd</option>
  <option value="WY">aaas</option>
  <option value="WY">qwer</option>
  <option value="WY">sqwqw</option>
  <option value="WY">cxncmx</option>
  <option value="WY">snamsnam</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you're going to copy-paste code straight from the documentation, at least link to it.

Comment: They are pretty clearly using the newer version of Select2, this only works for the older version.

Comment: Yes I am 4.0.0. I found what I wanted, custom matcher, I'll have to skim much more slowly, I was looking for things like order, sort, or alpha. Thank you