# How to get query string or container in sorter function in jquery-select2

Tags: jquery-select2

Is there any way to get the query string or the element I've attached select2 to in the sorter function? I have multiple dropdowns on the page so getting the query string will not work this way:

```
$('.select2-search__field').val().toLowerCase()
```

I'm working with a local data set so the options are already in the dropdown.

```
$('.js-select').select2({
    sorter: select2Sorter
});

function select2Sorter(results) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 - Sorting results by query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991217/select2-sorting-results-by-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer to your question is "no". You can't reference any of select2 inners from `sorter` function

#### Why so?

If you look at select2 sources, particularly the [`result.js` file, line 93](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/73e50ae92c71ae829df7eb84b456654ca47d9022/src/js/select2/results.js#L93), you'll see that the `sort` function looks like this:

```
Results.prototype.sort = function (data) {
    var sorter = this.options.get('sorter');

    return sorter(data);
};
```

So, it does not propagate any context to the passed `sorter` function, not does it provide any more arguments.

#### Solution

A quick-and-dirty way of fixing that is to override the `sort` function to provide `this` context. This can be done in the following way (assuming you have the `*.full.js` version of select2):

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/results').prototype.sort = function (data) {
    var sorter = this.options.get("sorter");

    // pass the `this` context
    return sorter.call(this, data);
};
```

Now, every time your `sorter` function is invoked, you'll have access to select2 inners, and can do whatever you want, e.g.

```
$('#e1').select2({
    sorter: function (data) {
        // get the search field of the current select2 element
        var $searchField = this.data.$element.data("select2")
            .$dropdown.find(".select2-search__field");

        // log it's value
        console.log($searchField.val());
        return data;
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjn2amps/) which demonstrates the concept.